# XML Praser : Detect repeating nodes

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to make a universal simple XML to array kind of script.

The idea is to detect which nodes are repeating so that is the tag name I need to loop

For example

Feed 1 :-

```
<carfeed>
<sometag>
<child>
Child content
</child>
</sometag>
<cars>
<car>
<name>Ford</name>
<color>Blue</color>
</car>
<car>
<name>Nissan</name>
<color>Red</color>
</car>
</cars>
</carfeed>
```

Feed 2:-

```
<vehicles>
<vehicle>
<name>Ford</name>
<color>Blue</color>
<type>Pickup</type>
</vehicle>
<vehicle>
<name>Nissan</name>
<color>Red</color>
<type>Car</type>
</vehicle>
</vehicles>
```

So in Feed 1 the tag to loop is car and Feed 2 it is vehicle.

The logic I have come up so far is the node that loops come consecutively is there are way to detect this.

Comment: what code did you come up with?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make a few assumptions here since I couldn't make much from the question.

1. You want to parse XML in php and need php code
2. You want to match the `<car>` tag in first xml file to `<vehicle>` tag in second xml file.

Based on the above assumption, here is the program for it

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($xmlData1,null, LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING); //$xmlData1 is the first xml 
$carsArr = array();
foreach ($xml1->cars->car as $car) {
    $carsArr[(string)$car->name] = array();
    $carsArr[(string)$car->name]= (string)$car->color; //create map of car name to color
}


$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($$xmlData2,null, LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING); //$xmlData2 is the second xml
foreach($xml2->vehicle as $vehicle) {
    $name = (string)$vehicle->name;
    if(isset($carsArr[$name])) {
        echo "Name:".$name.",Color:".$carsArr[$name].",Type:".$vehicle->type."
";
    }
}
```

The output will be:

> Name:Ford,Color:Blue,Type:Pickup
>  Name:Nissan,Color:Red,Type:Car

In this way, you can detect repeating nodes between two files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to write a script that automatically detects the repeating nodes rather than explicitly searching and looping through "cars->car" and "vehicle". A universal code that detects which tag are looping.

Comment: Could you still clarify because I am confused. From what I understood, you want to detect repeating nodes in both files. True? Could you give an example?

Comment: @KaranAshar I think he wants to write code that parses **ONE** XML file at a time and detect nodes that have at least one sibling with the same name, like `<car>` in his 1st example. He wants his code to work on **ANY** XML regardless of how the nodes are named.